# Load balancing on ESB

Tags: mule, load-balancing, biztalk, soa, esb

I've got an assignment in which I'm supposed to test load balancing capabilities of a chosen ESB. MS BizTalk was suggested, but I would really prefer something cross-platform, like MuleESB.

I face following problem: I have 4 services (lets call them S1, S2, S3, S4) and 3 hosts (H1, H2, H3). I'd like to run services on hosts like this:

```
H1: S1, S2
H2: S2, S3
H3: S3, S4
```

and connect them to ESB.

What I would like to do is having some exposed virtual service S2 provided by ESB, that would balance its load on H1 and H2, and similiar thing with S3 on H2 and H3.

Judging by [THIS](https://devcentral.f5.com/articles/load-balancing-as-an-esb-service#.Uz-8WlcRc5w) ESBs are not exactly known for their robust load balancing capabilities and one should use external NLB solution, hard or software. Is ESB (be it BizTalk or something open-source) capable of dealing with load balancing in such a situation? If yes, how would I proceed with creating that specific case?

Answer (score 2):

For sure, BizTalk can handle that scenario with load balancing happening at the two points where it can play a meaningful role.

For clarity, 'service' really has two meaning here.

1. The service interface (like the network endpoint be it true Web Service, HTTP listener, custom API, etc...doesn't matter).
2. The service that does the actual processing on the incoming data (like transformation, validation, business logic, etc).

1 is handled by various Windows components like NLB (Network Load Balancing) where incoming requests are spread across multiple IP's.

2 is handled with BizTalk by creating multiple BizTalk instances on different computers.  These instances then automatically share the work among them.

Comment: Could you provide any sources on "how to"? I don't even know how to ask Google anymore, since I've tried things like "load balancing esb", "load balancing biztalk", etc - all the obvious...

Comment: On 2) The BizTalk community typically uses Scale Out which also provides High Availability.  "Load balancing" is actually incidental to these configurations as BizTalk will just do it automatically.  Start here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa546759.aspx and http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15223

Comment: On 1) Load balancing network connections is, by now, a rather trivial task.  Windows NLB is perfectly serviceable in many scenarios.  Many environments already have a network device with this feature so the decision is often an administrative or policy one.

Comment: In BizTalk, NLB can be used for direct / synchronous protocols like web services (NLB has round robin and sticky routing capabilities). For incoming asynchronous traffic like queues, a (batched) competing consumer model is used by the receive locations to alternate load. But as BoatSeller alludes, the receiving of messages and the processing or routing of them should be decoupled via the messagebox, which then allows the load to be dispersed across all all subscribing servers and processes.

Answer (score 1):

I think you sum it up help here "ESBs are not exactly known for their robust load balancing capabilities". NLBs have robust algorithms for load distribution (including instance health checking).

Mule doesn't have such feature OOTB so you'll end-up having to code your own, which can be tedious if you want to build a full fledged balancer. If you trim the features down (no health checking, random load distribution) then, sure, you can get away with a pretty simple HTTP bridge.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with David, full functional enterprise solution for load balancing http/https services would to be to use either hardware(i.e. cisco ace or f5) balancer or cheaper software solution like apache httpd with mod_proxy_balancer.

With Mule ESB you can have simple implementation(without sticky sessions etc.) of round-robin load balancing like this:

```
<flow name="22878770_load-balancing-on-esbFlow1" doc:name="22878770_load-balancing-on-esbFlow1">
<http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP" method="GET"/>
<scripting:component doc:name="Script">
    <scripting:script engine="Groovy">
        def rand = new java.util.Random()
        int max = 10
        return rand.nextInt(max+1)
    </scripting:script>
</scripting:component>
<choice doc:name="Choice">
    <when expression="#[payload&lt;=3]">
        <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="yandex.com" port="80" method="GET" followRedirects="true" doc:name="HTTP1"/>
    </when>
    <when expression="#[payload&lt;=6]">
        <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="google.com" port="80" method="GET" followRedirects="true" doc:name="HTTP2"/>
    </when>
    <otherwise>
        <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="baidu.com" port="80" method="GET"  followRedirects="true" doc:name="HTTP3"/>
    </otherwise>
</choice>
</flow>
```